# Error compiling sample JavaFx code with MediaPlayer in Eclipse

Tags: javafx

while compiling the below code:

```
package Sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Sample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer( new Media(getClass().getResource("Sample.flv").toExternalForm()));
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(player);

        root.getChildren().add( mediaView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1024, 768);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();


        player.play();

    }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager (in unnamed module @0x3d3deed) cannot access class com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.glass.utils to unnamed module @0x3d3deed
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.lambda$new$0(NativeMediaManager.java:110)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.<init>(NativeMediaManager.java:107)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager$NativeMediaManagerInitializer.<clinit>(NativeMediaManager.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getDefaultInstance(NativeMediaManager.java:90)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.canPlayProtocol(MediaManager.java:78)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Locator.java:239)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:393)
    at Sample.Sample.start(Sample.java:31)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application Sample.Sample
```

I am learning to use JavaFx atm, could this be caused by bad configuration of JavaFx on my Eclipse or something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What JDK version are you running? This compiles and runs just fine for me with JDK 1.8 (using IntelliJ IDEA)

Comment: I am using JDK 11.0.1

Comment: I know that JavaFX is no longer included with the JDK as of Java 11. Have you correctly installed it? I'm afraid I can't help further with that, though, as I've not used 11 yet

Comment: That's the thing, I have doubts if I installed it correctly. However I am able to create windows with buttons and images so perhaps I installed Java Fx not entirely correct and it affects video display only?

Comment: What are your launch configurations? I'm assuming your own code is not within a module, correct? In that case, I'm also assuming your have something like `--add-modules javafx.controls`. However, the media classes are inside the `javafx.media` module; you must include it in the `--add-modules` command. All JavaFX modules _must_ be on the modulepath.

Comment: All your assumptions are correct. I added media module. However now there is a new compilation error complaining about MEDIA_UNSUPPORTED. The video is .flv file with audio encoded in MP3 and video encoded in VP6. I am clueless again ...

Comment: See [`javafx.scene.media`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) for information on what formats/encodings are supported by JavaFX.

Comment: Oh, the flv is no longer on the list. I will try MP4 as soon as I get home.

Comment: Thank you, Slaw, using MP4 instead of FLV did the trick.